# PuTTY exits after entering password (log : “This account is currently not available”)

Tags: ssh, putty

I'm new to the SSH console. After entering the IP address, port and password my hosting provider supplied me with, the PuTTY console exits immediately.

When I enable logging to "All session output" it returns the following:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2015.02.08 19:14:58 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
Using username "u702594423".
u702594423@31.220.20.85's password: 
Last login: Sun Feb  8 17:59:11 2015 from ip-5-104-119-129.fiber.nl

This account is currently not available.
```

Does anyone have a suggestion of how to fix this?

I opened a ticket with the hosting provider, but they haven't responded yet.

Comment: I agree with Nick: the `Last login` message suggests that you are getting logged in, but then you are getting logged out immediately (automatically). Can you use `pscp` or `psftp` to get into the account and look at files? Do you know what kind of system you are logging in to? (I.e., it's probably some form of Linux; do you know which one?)

Answer (score 3):

Opening a ticket with the hosting provider is likely the best move.

It looks like the "This account is currently not available" message is coming from the shell which is invoked after logging in.

It's likely that the account which you're attempting to ssh into has been disabled by the hosting provider or by an entry in the shell rc files.